# Function that matches a specific pattern in factor-scores and returns number of expected cases (ltm package in R)

Tags: r, function, object

In the context of IRT modelling in R, I would like to know how to build a function that takes factor scores and a pattern of interest as input and then returns the expected number of cases matching that pattern.
This code

```
item1 <- cbind(1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0)
item2 <- cbind(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)
item3 <- cbind(1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0)
item4 <- cbind(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
Items <- matrix(c(item1, item2, item3, item4), ncol=4)

library(ltm)
fit <- ltm(Items ~ z1, IRT.param=TRUE) 
mle <- ltm::factor.scores(fit,method="EB",prior=FALSE) 
mle
# mle$score.dat$Exp
pattern_of_interest <- c(0,0,0,1)
```

returns that factor-scores:

```
  Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Obs   Exp      z1     se.z1
1      0      0      0      0   2 1.948 -96.517 12529.631
2      0      0      0      1   2 1.706  -2.303     3.647
3      0      0      1      0   1 0.744  -0.076     0.303
4      0      1      0      1   1 0.668  -0.864     1.494
5      0      1      1      0   1 0.333  -0.052     0.261
6      1      0      1      0   2 1.051   1.173     1.711
7      1      0      1      1   1 1.225   1.844     2.575
8      1      1      0      1   1 0.199   0.323     0.297
9      1      1      1      1   1 0.834  93.748 10003.995
```

The function that I am looking for takes `mle` and `pattern_of_interest` as input and returns the corresponding value in `mle$score.dat$Exp` (using the pattern 0|0|0|1 the correct value is 1.706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge(mle$score.dat, as.data.frame(t(setNames(pattern_of_interest, nm = paste0("Item ", 1:4)))), all = FALSE)["Exp"]
```

Comment: Nice, great answer!